# Error extends AccountController.php in magento

Tags: magento, extends

I'm trying to extend the core AccountController.php -> app/code/core/Mage/Customer copied it to app/code/local/Mage/ and add a log to see which extends properly.

```
In the file AccountController.php (app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers)
...
...
public function createPostAction() {
        Mage::log('In app/code/local/Mage/', null, 'test.log', true);
...
...

AND CORE (only test)
In the file AccountController.php (app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers)
...
...
public function createPostAction() {
        Mage::log('In app/code/core/Mage/', null, 'test.log', true);
...
...
```

And does not go through code/local/ Mage but by CORE.
I need to configure something or it fails?

Answer (score 2):

The logic through which controller class definitions are loaded builds the path to the file *above* the explicit include paths on which the autoloader relies. This means no local vs. core precedence.

You need to creat a controller rewrite by specifying a directory under the xpath `frontend/routers/customer/args/modules/your_module`

The latter node needs the `before` attribute set to `Mage_Customer` and you will need to create an *`AccountController.php`* with a `createPostAction()` method. Depending on your needs you may or may not need to extend from *and require* the core account controller class.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to require the original controller:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';
```

Normally you need to do this with rewriting a controller the xml way...i havent checked in code, but maybe this is the problem.

I would recommend to do it the regular way via config.xml

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

Comment: I just try creating a module adding bypasses everything but the module always going by CORE